# Определить ближайший прямоугольник или квадрат среди представленных по заданным размерностям

Tags: математика, перебор, прямоугольники

Задача запрограммировать следующую логику:

Есть 5 картинок, на котором изображены возможные размеры помещения:
1.5x1.5, 3x3, 3x6, 6x6 и 6x12.

На вход поступают реальные размеры помещения, заданные пользователем, такая же пара вещественных чисел.

Требуется показать тот вариант из пяти, который больше подходит под заданные размеры.

Вопрос в том есть ли для этой задачи математическая модель, с помощью которой получится запрограммировать?

Comment: Для начала, вам нужно формализовать и описать алгоритм *"больше подходит под заданные размеры"*. Исходя из этого - перенести его в код.

Comment: Это не определено. Скажем, 1.5x1.6 можно показать квадрат 1.5x1.5.

Comment: *Это не определено.* Однако это ОБЯЗАНО быть определено. Никакая матмодель не моделирует "поди туда не знаю куда". Изобретай однозначный числовой критерий, который позволит для каждого из пяти вариантов посчитать меру отклонения и выбрать тот вариант, отклонение которого минимально.

Comment: Это надо определить, иначе, `1,75х1,75` к чему отнести, а `1,5х3`, а `4х4` ?

Comment: Хорошо, а если будет полный набор (появятся варианты 3x12, 1.5x6 и т.д.) -  в этом случае задачу возможно решить по-другому или все-равно требуется выдумывать эту меру различия?

Comment: Без разницы, численный критерий обязан быть. Или позволяйте пользователю не свободный ввод, а выбор из имеющихся вариантов.